# If five coins are flipped simultaneously, find the probability of each of the following:

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> If five coins are flipped simultaneously, find the probability of each of the following:
>
> (a) At least one coin lands heads;

My answer:$\frac{2^5 -1}{2^5}$. I took the complement for the numerator.

> (b) At most one coin lands heads.

My answer: $\frac{6}{2^5}$. I counted how many times heads appears $1$ or $0$ times.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good job!!

For part a, notice that this is the OPPOSITE of (no coin lands heads <=> all coins land tails), which is $\displaystyle \left(\frac12 \right)^5=\frac{1}{32}$ chance.

For part b, any $5$ of the coins can land heads, if in total one coin lands heads. If no coin lands heads, that can be done in $1$ way. That is $\displaystyle \frac{6}{32}=\frac{3}{16}$ chance.

In general, take a look at the binomial distribution.

Comment: For this homework we have to assume we don't the binomial distribution or any combination numbers.

Comment: Alright! Then just count the ways to pick k coins to be heads, from n coins.

Answer (score 3):

Your answers are correct. In terms of notation I would use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), where the probability of $k$ successes out of $n$ attempts equals:

$${n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

1. The probability of at least one heads equals 1 minus the probability of no heads:
   $$1 - {5 \choose 0} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^0 \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^5 = 1 - \frac{1}{32} = \frac{31}{32}$$
2. The probability of having at most one heads equals:
   $${5 \choose 0} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^0 \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^5 + {5 \choose 1} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^1 \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^4 = \frac{6}{32}$$

Comment: For this homework we have to assume we don't the binomial distribution or any combination numbers, because my professor hasn't gone over it yet..